# After the desktop bridge app is uninstalled, ProgramData\Packages\{appName} still has a folder "S-1-5-21-****"

Tags: uwp

I found that after my app was installed, the `S-1-5-21-***\SystemAppData\Helium` folder was automatically created under `ProgramData\Packages\{appName}`, and there was also a cache folder and two dat files.

So, how to Ensure that all contents of the app will be deleted after uninstalling?

Comment: I made a test, the SystemAppData\Helium folder will be deleted after the app is uninstalled. The other folder does not contain anything. Why do you still want to remove them all?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Although the folder does not contain any content after uninstallation, since the folder does not contain any files, why do we need to keep this folder?
If the folder ProgramData\Packages\{appName} is automatically deleted after uninstallation, it may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After confirming with the team, I have some things to share.

First of all, the platform does attempts to remove the C:\ProgramData\Packages{appName}<userSid>\SystemAppData folder at package uninstall, but like other file system locations, the remove is best-effort basis, i.e., even if we hit an error we don’t want to fail the uninstall. So you should only have an empty C:\ProgramData\Packages{appName}<userSid> folder left after uninstall.

Cleanup of this per-user folder happens when the current user is being removed.
It is safe to manually delete the empty per-user folder, if desired, but it requires admin privilege.

If the existence of an empty and harmless folder is not causing any issue, then there should be no problem.

Comment: The team mentioned that in the feature release version of Windows 10, this behavior will be changed. The empty folder will also be deleted.